# How to do array from the string ?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an adress such as https://stackoverflow.com/#/schedulePage/some/another , how can I make it to an array with elements after # ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var urlToSplit = "https://stackoverflow.com/#/schedulePage/some/another"

var onlyAfterHash = urlToSplit.split("/#/")[1];
var result = onlyAfterHash.split("/");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `""` is this expected?Also you can avoid extra variable by doing this
`urlToSplit.split("#")[1].split("/");`

Comment: Edited the code to have better result

Comment: what means [1] in this urlToSplit.split("#")[1]; ?

Comment: to get only the part after the #... the result of `split()` is an array, so get the second part only

Comment: need it without quetes " "

Comment: which quotes are you referring to?

Comment: In console result is : ["", "schedulePage", "some", "another"] - 4 arrays (where did the quotes come from in your result ?);  I need ["schedulePage", "some", "another"] .

Comment: This only a printing style to show those are strings.. when you use any of these values they are with quotes..

Answer (score 0):

Use the *split* function

```
var str = "https://stackoverflow.com/#/schedulePage/some/another";
var res = str.split("#");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want something like this.First here I just split out the string by `#`, grab the second part of split result i.e index **1** then again splitting the result with `/` and finally filter out the empty string from the generated array.

```js
var string = 'https://stackoverflow.com/#/schedulePage/some/another';
var result = string.split('#')[1].split('/');
var filtered = result.filter((entry)=>entry.trim() != '');
console.log(filtered);
```